# Using workmanager with firsebase messaging and i get this error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-workmanager

I am using flutter Workmanager to send notifications when application is in background or in terminated state specifically. I have initialized and configured firebasemessaging and flutter awesome notification services in my application but when my application background process starts then I get this error.
No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp() in Flutter and Firebase

Below is my code of what I am doing.

This is how i am implementing it.

// Firebase messaging services

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
      content: NotificationContent(
          id: -1, // -1 is replaced by a random number
          channelKey: 'alerts',
          title: message.notification!.title,
          body: message.notification!.body,
          bigPicture: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/cms-storage-bucket/d406c736e7c4c57f5f61.png',
          largeIcon: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/cms-storage-bucket/0dbfcc7a59cd1cf16282.png',
          //'asset://assets/images/balloons-in-sky.jpg',
          notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.BigPicture,
          category: NotificationCategory.Message,
          wakeUpScreen: true,
          fullScreenIntent: true,
          autoDismissible: false,
      ),
      actionButtons: [
        NotificationActionButton(key: 'REDIRECT', label: 'Redirect'),
        NotificationActionButton(
            key: 'REPLY',
            label: 'Reply Message',
            requireInputText: true,
            actionType: ActionType.SilentAction
        ),
        NotificationActionButton(
            key: 'DISMISS',
            label: 'Dismiss',
            actionType: ActionType.DismissAction,
            isDangerousOption: true)
      ]);
  print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
}
```

// Flutter Awesome notifications

```
Future<void> initializeLocalNotifications() async {
  await AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
      null, //'resource://drawable/res_app_icon',//
      [
        NotificationChannel(
            channelKey: 'alerts',
            channelName: 'Alerts',
            channelDescription: 'Notification tests as alerts',
            playSound: true,
            onlyAlertOnce: true,
            groupAlertBehavior: GroupAlertBehavior.Children,
            importance: NotificationImportance.High,
            defaultPrivacy: NotificationPrivacy.Private,
            defaultColor: Colors.deepPurple,
            ledColor: Colors.deepPurple)
      ],
      debug: true);
}
```

// Flutter WorkManager

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async{

    try { //add code execution
      await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken().then((token)async{
        await http.post(
          Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'),
          headers: <String, String>{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization':
            'key=AAAAwdRDro8:APA91bFKNnopHADNdDnO5NOGEMNK96fc-lm23XAup1MOvx3k5Ec_3VXLhKIEn8ue-uJb7jf8yECsqk1pNonmi9oDC0hjvjFAsIZLeH2xc_-4jusBJa7jK4_E5lgry9Fo7Gr_2PxDJTht',
          },
          body: jsonEncode(
            <String, dynamic>{
              'notification': <String, dynamic>{
                'body': "Inbound and Outbound notifications details",
                'title': "Safeline Push Notification",
              },
              'priority': 'high',
              'data': <String, dynamic>{
                'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
                'id': '1',
                'status': 'done'
              },
              "to": token,
            },
          ),
        );
        print('done');
      });
    } catch(err) {
      Logger().e(err.toString()); // Logger flutter package, prints error on the debug console
      throw Exception(err);
    }

    return Future.value(true);
  });
}
```

// My main function

```
Future<void> main() async {
  //You will need to initialize AppThemeNotifier class for theme changes.
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform
  );
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  Workmanager().initialize(
      callbackDispatcher, // The top level function, aka callbackDispatcher
      isInDebugMode: true // If enabled it will post a notification whenever the task is running. Handy for debugging tasks
  );
  // Periodic task registration
  Workmanager().registerPeriodicTask(
    "periodic-task-identifier",
    "simplePeriodicTask",
    // When no frequency is provided the default 15 minutes is set.
    // Minimum frequency is 15 min. Android will automatically change your frequency to 15 min if you have configured a lower frequency.
    frequency: Duration(minutes: 15),
    backoffPolicy: BackoffPolicy.exponential,
  );
  initializeLocalNotifications();
  AppTheme.init();
  await GetStorage.init();

  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);

  runApp(
    MultiProvider(providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: AppNotifier()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: LoginProvider()),
      ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: InboundProvider(),),
    ],
    child: MyApp(),),
  );
}
```

[image: This is the error i get]